# Alternative of contact to contact relation usecase in salesforce

Tags: account, contact, accountcontactrelation, households

I have a business case wherein I have to create a contact-to-contact relationship.

here is the usecase in a diagram

[image]

I could think of only the below options to resolve this issue.

**option 1.** Convert the `Record Type: PeopleService` to `Account`

**option 2.** Keep the `Amy Jackson` `Record Type: PeopleService` as `Contact` but while creating `People Service` do not assign any `Account` so that Salesforce creates the default `HouseHold Account` i.e `Jackson Household`.

later set the parent of `Jackson Household` Account  to `City Site` and set `Jack Ryan`'s Account to `Jackson Household`

Option one seems pretty easy but I am still confused about which one would be the best suited here

Comment: _Salesforce creates the default HouseHold Account_ - this is a product-specific behavior in Salesforce, it's not a generic default. What SF product are you using? Also, it would help to understand what real-world relationship you're trying to model here.

Comment: NPSP we are using where in HouseHold is supported

Comment: NPSP supports contact-to-contact relationships out of the box: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/constituent-data-management-with-nonprofit-success-pack/connect-contacts-using-relationships . It also supports the indirect relationship path via Account (Household or otherwise) and/or Affiliation.